Understand computational formula of Cramer von Mises statistic
I've found this question that explains how to get from the integral to computational formula of Cramer von Mises statistic: Computational formula for Cramer-von Mises test statistic.
The answer is quite complete.
What I don't understand is how a come from this step:
$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^n \frac13\left(\left(U_{(i+1)}-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3-\left(U_{(i)}-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3\right)$
To this:
$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n \frac13\left(\left(U_{(i)}-\frac{i-1}{n}\right)^3-\left(U_{(i)}-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3\right)$

$$\begin{align}&\sum_{i=0}^n \left(\left(U_{(i+1)}-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3-\left(U_{(i)}-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3\right)\\
=&\sum_{i=0}^n \left(U_{(i+1)}-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3-\sum_{i=0}^n\left(U_{(i)}-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3\\
=&\sum_{j=1}^{n+1} \left(U_{(j)}-\frac{j-1}{n}\right)^3-\sum_{i=0}^n\left(U_{(i)}-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3\\
=&\sum_{j=1}^n \left(U_{(j)}-\frac{j-1}{n}\right)^3+\require{cancel}\cancel{(U_{(n+1)}-1)^3}-\sum_{i=1}^n\left(U_{(i)}-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3-\require{cancel}\cancel{(U_{(0)}-\frac0n)^3}\\
=&\sum_{j=1}^n \left(U_{(j)}-\frac{j-1}{n}\right)^3-\sum_{i=1}^n\left(U_{(i)}-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3\\
=&\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\left(U_{(i)}-\frac{i-1}{n}\right)^3-\left(U_{(i)}-\frac{i}{n}\right)^3\right)
\end{align}$$
because $U_{(0)}:=0, U_{(n+1)}:=1$.
